# Unused variables warning in address.call return tuple (bool, bytes memory)

Tags: solidity

I have the following code fragment.

```
function forward(address destination, bytes memory data) public { 
    (bool res, bytes memory retData) = destination.call(data);
    assert(res);
}
```

Since retData is not used, I am getting the following warning (compiled with solidity 0.5.0):

```
Compilation warnings encountered:

/Users/ivica/Documents/deka/hekate.reloaded/digits-node/contracts/IdentityProxy.sol:55:20:
Warning: Unused local variable.
        (bool res, bytes memory retData) = destination.call(data);
                   ^------------------^
```

**Question:** how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;

contract Test {

    function forward(address destination, bytes memory data) public { 
        (bool res, ) = destination.call(data);
        assert(res);
    }
}
```

Basically we are omitting the second assignment.